# Spring Integration: Jdbc-inbound-adapter is it transactional when using adice-chain

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below configuration for my jdbc-inbound-adapter:

```
    <si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcInboundAdapter"
    channel="queueChannel" data-source="myDataSource"
    auto-startup="true"
    query="SELECT * FROM STAGE_TABLE WHERE STATUS='WAITING'  FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED"
    update="UPDATE STAGE_TABLE SET STATUS='IN_PROGRESS' WHERE ID IN (:Id)"
    max-rows-per-poll="100" row-mapper="rowMapper"
    update-per-row="true">

    <si:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <si:advice-chain> 
            <ref bean="txAdvice"/> 
            <ref bean="inboundAdapterConfiguration"/> 
        </si:advice-chain>
    </si:poller>
</si-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="false"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

My question is does the both select and update statements would be executed in the same transaction.

In the spring-integration documentation it does not specify clearly about the transaction when advice-chain is used. (I am using spring-integration-jdbc-2.2.0.RC2.jar)
Please see section 18.1.1 Poller Transaction Support:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RC1/reference/html/transactions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very old version (and only a release candidate at that, not a GA release. The current version is `3.0.2.RELEASE` the latest `2.2.x` is `2.2.6.RELEASE`. Please upgrade to one of those.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/

Yes, it's all done in the same transaction.

Are you referring to the old documentation too? The [current documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#d4e6968) says

"A very important feature of the poller for JDBC usage is the option to wrap the poll operation in a transaction,..".

The transaction is started, the message source is invoked (to get the results) and the downstream flow all occurs in the transaction (unless you hand off to another thread, in which case the transaction will commit at that time).

In fact, the update is done right after the select (and before the message is sent), but the commit doesn't occur until the downstream flow is complete.

Your channel is called `queueChannel`; if it really is a queue channel, that means that the transaction will commit as soon as the message is stored in the queue.

If you feel documentation improvements are required, please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Thanks Gary. 1. About the Spring-Integration Jar Version: Our current build is in already in Production. We will be releasing an another build in another 6 weeks. We have all the other Spring Jars of version 3.1.2. Which would you think would be good 2.2.6 or 3.0.2. 2.The queueChannel is the QueueChannel with a capacity of 200. 3. Abt Documentation: I was searching for the poller transaction details and I came across the 2.0.0 document.

Comment: On a different note:  I have a bean which implements the RowMapper<StatusRequestDB> interface to read the records. Should this bean's scope be singleton or prototype to speed up the process of reading. we get around 400K messages daily to get processed.

Comment: 2.0.0 is ancient; there are links to more recent document versions on the project page at the first link in my answer. `RowMapper` should be stateless and it's only injected once anyway, so it won't make a difference whether it's singleton or not. 2.2.6 shouldn't require any work on your part; you may have to make some minor changes to go to 3.0.x; see the Wiki for details. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki